# Add combobox text to its Itemssource

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, combobox

I have a combobox binded to a table called `Tenderness` through MVVM. I'm using Entity Framework.It displays all the records properly, but I need to add another functionality to it. Suppose the user types in text which is not contained inside the combobox's Itemssource, I want to be able to add it directly to the table and then update the Itemssource as well. Now I have been able to do this without MVVM, I would want to know, how to achieve it using MVVM.

Comment: Could you please show how you "have been able to do this without MVVM"?

Comment: Add a delegate `Lost Focus` event handler to the textbox part of the combox, check for current text, if it is contained in the combobox items, then skip, otherwise add it to the database, and refresh the items of the combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do what you did previously in the `LostFocus` event handler in the setter of a source property that you bind to the `Text` property of the `ComboBox`.

**View Model:**

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };

private string _text;
public string Text
{
    get { return _text; }
    set
    {
        _text = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Text));

        //add the missing value...
        if (!Items.Contains(_text))
            Items.Add(_text);
    }
}

private string _selectedItem;
public string SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        _selectedItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
```

Comment: Yes this adds the new added text to the ObservableCollection, now how do I add it to the database?

Comment: That's a completely different question. But you do it just as you did before in your LostFocus event handler. You asked on how "how to achieve this using MVVM" and this has been answered.

Comment: Thank you! But can I raise an event when the ObservableCollection is changed and make it add the new items to the entity?

Comment: The ObservableCollection class already raises the CollectionChanged event. So you could handle this one.

Comment: Last question, how will I tell the Observable Collection that which is the new item that has been added, inorder to add it to the database?

Comment: You mean in the event handler? Check the e.AddedItems property.

Comment: `e.NewItems[0]` where '0' is the index, did the trick. Thank you very much.